# How to put data in a PyPi python package and retrieve via pip?

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to package some data alongside the scripts within a package of mine: https://pypi.org/project/taxon2wikipedia/0.0.4/

The source distribution seems to contain  the files that I need, but when trying to use the package I get the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/taxon2wikipedia/dicts/phrase_start_dict.json'
```

The "data" and "dicts" folders are not there in "site-packages/taxon2wikipedia", but are present in the package when I manually download it? Any suggestions on why it might be happening?

Thanks!

### Edit: extra information

I already have a MANIFEST.in file with `recursive-include src *.rq *.py *.jinja *json`, and even changing it to other similar options,  it did not work.
I am using a pyproject.toml configuration and a mock setup.py to run `setuptools.setup()`.
I run `python3 -m build` to build the package. Maybe the problem lies there?

This is the source repository by the way: https://github.com/lubianat/taxon2wikipedia

The files in PyPI are all correct, but don't seem to be downloaded when I pip install the package.

### Edit 2 - Related question

[Why does "pip install" not include my package_data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791179/why-does-pip-install-not-include-my-package-data-files)

It seems to be some problem with how pip installs the package. The solution is different as in my case the files seem to be at the correct directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this blog post which helped me solve the issue:
https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/pypkg-data/
In the end, I was missing
`[options.package_data] * = *.json *.jinja *.rq`
from my `setuf.cfg`

Answer (score 1):

[You need a `MANIFEST.in` file in your source directory to tell the packaging process which non-Python files need to come along in a built package.](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/)

In your case, a `MANIFEST.in` file with

```
recursive-include taxon2wikipedia *.json
```

should do the trick.

Since `.whl` files are zips, you can use `zipinfo dist/yournewwheel.whl` to see that the files are there too before pushing a release.

Comment: Thanks! 
I already have a MANIFEST.in file with `recursive-include src *.rq *.py *.jinja *json`, and even changing it to your option, it did not work. 


I am using a pyproject.toml configuration and  a mock setup.py to run `    setuptools.setup()`. I run `python3 -m build` to build the package. Maybe the problem lies there?

Comment: The repo you've linked doesn't have a `MANIFEST.in`, and it's not using `pyproject.toml` for project metadata either. (Have you pushed your changes..?) `python -m build` is fine; it uses the backend you've specified in `pyproject.toml`. You don't need `setup.py` at all.

Comment: Indeed I had not pushed the changes (sorry about the mess)

In the end was a bit of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791179/why-does-pip-install-not-include-my-package-data-files

But mostly I should have included 
```
[options.package_data]
* = *.json *.jinja *.rq
```
In my setup.cfg . This seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much for the kind answers!

Comment: I would recommend moving fully to `pyproject.toml` instead of `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg`, e.g. with https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/