# apache-airflow fails install

Tags: python, docker, pip, airflow

I'm trying to install apache-airflow the recommended way with `pip install apache-airflow`.  During the install of pendulum (a dependency), I get an error:

```
  error: can't copy 'pendulum/parsing': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

I think it's related to [Python distutils error: "[directory]... doesn't exist or not a regular file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712033/python-distutils-error-directory-doesnt-exist-or-not-a-regular-file), but that doesn't give an answer as to how one resolves this when using pip.  Pulling the tar for pendulum and installing using `python setup.py install` works, but then when subsequently I do `pip install apache-airflow` again, it sees that pendulum is already installed, UNINSTALLS, and then tries to install again using pip, resulting in the same error.  I'm using a docker container and installing python-setuptools with apt-get before I do any of this.  Here's my dockerfile, fwiw...

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.1
MAINTAINER a curious dev 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-setuptools python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev zip wget

ENV SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes

RUN wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/57/71fc910edcd937b72aa0ef51c8f5734fbd8c011fa1480fce881433847ec8/pendulum-2.0.4.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf pendulum-2.0.4.tar.gz

RUN cd pendulum-2.0.4/ && python setup.py install

RUN pip install apache-airflow

CMD airflow initdb && airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Does anyone see anything I'm doing wrong?  I haven't found anyone else with this error so I think there's something really obvious I'm missing.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade `pip` first.

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-setuptools python-pip python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev zip wget
ENV SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install apache-airflow
CMD airflow initdb && airflow webserver -p 8080
```

seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help; I appreciate your time!  That's odd that apt-get doesn't install the latest version of pip, right?

Comment: System packages usually lag a lot behind reality for Python packages (on Debian, usually ridiculously so; on Ubuntu, slightly less). Either way, `python-pip` installs 8.1.1 and we're at 18.1 now (though the versioning scheme has changed along the way).